# pairing image object with screen position coordinates -- python

Tags: python, image, coordinates, screen

I am building a game using Python. To skip the details and jump directly into the problem, I have 3 images presented on screen on a random location each time.

```
......
position1 = (250,0)
position2 = (0,0)
position3 = (-250,0)

all_combinations = list(itertools.permutations([position1, position2, position3]))
random.shuffle(all_combinations)

for combination in all_combinations:
    image1 = stimuli.Picture('images\image1.png', position=combination[0])
    image2 = stimuli.Picture('images\image2.png', position=combination[1])
    image3 = stimuli.Picture('images\image3.png', position=combination[2])
....
```

And later on in the code I am presenting these images on the screen. The player has to choose one image using the keyboard. How can i pair each image with their screen coordinates location, since this is random each time? The ultimate goal is: if image1 is on the left and they press the left button to say that "if image1 is chosen ... do this" but I can't find a way to specify which image is on the left.

Thanks!

Comment: cant you keep it as `(image1, combination[0])` ?

Comment: image on the left has the smallest `x` - so you could use `min()` or `sort()`. But if you know positions at start then on left is `(-250,0)` and then on the left is image with `x = -250` and you can check `if combination[0][0] == -250: on_left = image1`

Comment: I don't know why you use `permutaion` and `shuffle` - you need only `shuffle`. And maybe you should shuffle list of images and first image after shuffling put on left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you use `permutation` and `shuffle` if you need only `shuffle`

I would shuffle filenames and keep position in the same order and then first image would be on left because it has the smallest `x` (`-250`)

```
positions = [(-250,0), (0,0), (250,0)]

filenames = ['images\image1.png', 'images\image2.png', 'images\image3.png']
          
random.shuffle(filenames)

images = []

for name, pos in zip(filenames, positions):
    img = stimuli.Picture(name, position=pos)
    images.append( img )
    
left_img  = images[0]
left_pos  = positions[0]
left_name = filenames[0]

center_img  = images[1]
center_pos  = positions[1]
center_name = filenames[1]

right_img  = images[2]
right_pos  = positions[2]
right_name = filenames[2]
```